# Deriving continuity equation using Div Theorem in opposite direction

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

In electromagnetism we have a charge conservation law that says $$\int_V \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV + \oint_{S=dV} \boldsymbol j \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol n}\,\,dS = 0$$ From here I want to prove the continuity equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol j=0$.

**easy way**

Apply divergence theorem on the second term and joining the integrals (by linearity of integration) $$\int_V \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol j \,\,dV = 0$$ from which continuity equation easily follows

**reverse**

I wanted to not solve it like this, but the other way around. So I nabla-ed both side. Since the volume and its boundary are fixed, the nabla can go inside the integral. $$\int_V\nabla \cdot \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} dV+ \int_{S=dV}\nabla\cdot(\boldsymbol j \cdot \hat{\boldsymbol n}) dS = 0$$

The first term can become a surface integral like the second one and we can join the together.

> Does this approach bring somewhere? I can't seem to go any further

Comment: What are you differentiating with respect to with the $\nabla$? Neither term depends on $x$ since you are integrating over a volume $V$.

Comment: well I use $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z)$. What I am integrating over does not influence (except for dummy variables) the functions I am integrating. For example I can integrate over a volume something that depends on time. This will simply be constant if it depends only on time of course. But apart from this example, I think it doesn't matter whether they depend on $x$ or not, to be integrated over the volume

Comment: What you have written is rather like writing $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x') \, dx'$: the integral's just a constant (independent of $x$).